# why ostriches cannot fly? physics explanation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, gravity

I'm looking for a physics explanation concerning to the fact "The ostriches cannot fly".

My statments:

1. During the time interval $\Delta$t of the upward wingbeat, the ostrich drops a distance h under the action of gravity: $h = \dfrac{g (\Delta t)^2}{2}$
2. In this way the maximum allowable time for free fall is: $\Delta t= \left(\dfrac{2 h}{g}\right)^{1/2}$
3. the period T for a complete up-and-down wing movement is twice of $\Delta t$, and the frequency for that should be $f=\dfrac{1}{T} = \dfrac{1}{2 \cdot \Delta t}$
4. The average upward force on the body of the ostrich must be equal to twice o the weight of the ostrich ($a_{up}-g=g$ implies that $a_{up}=2\cdot g$ and $F_{winds}=2 \cdot P$)
5. The existence of the frictional forces

Adding the facts the wings of the ostrichs should be strong ($F_{winds}$ too large) and fast (T large) and this king of the wings don't exist in the nature because the energy consuption ($ E = F_{up} \cdot h \cdot t_{fly}$) is very large compared to the chemical reserves of the ostrich.

Comment: It's simpler than this. Ratite birds are fundamentally different from other birds in lacking a reinforced, keeled brisket bone (sternum). Thus their ribcages simply will not support the stresses the brisket would feel in thrusting enough air downwards to lift off.  So they could not fly, whatever kind of wing they might be kitted with. Ratites most likely split from the theropods separately from other birds, and, from their bone morphology, are thought never to have flown (whereas in the late 20th C some biologists thought they might be birds who lost their flight).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about ornithology and not physics.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos: Only miracles do not follow the laws of nature. The laws of nature are the laws of physics.